# How do I return multiple values in Angular2 Typescript

Tags: angular, filter, pagination, angular-material

I am trying to return multiple values in typescript when implementing both the filter and pagination function in md-table. when I run the code I get the error Unreachable code detected.

```
 return Observable.merge(...displayPatientDataChanges).map(() => {
   const startIndex = this._paginator.pageIndex * this._paginator.pageSize;
   const data = this._patientDatabase.data.slice();
   return data.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);

 // I get the error here on the second return function
   return this._patientDatabase.data.slice().filter((item: Patient) => {
     let searchStr = (item.firstname + item.lastname).toLowerCase();
     return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) != -1;
   });

 });
}

disconnect() {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because the methods ends after reaching:

```
return data.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
```

Which means that the following code is never reached, an therefor the error `Unreachable code detected`:

```
return this._patientDatabase.data.slice().filter((item: Patient) => {
     let searchStr = (item.firstname + item.lastname).toLowerCase();
     return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) != -1;
});
```

If you want to return both values then, you need to return an array or object:

```
const something1 = data.splice(startIndex, this._paginator.pageSize);
const something2 = this._patientDatabase.data.slice().filter((item: Patient) => {
     let searchStr = (item.firstname + item.lastname).toLowerCase();
     return searchStr.indexOf(this.filter.toLowerCase()) != -1;
});
return [something1, something2] // or {something1, something2}
```

Comment: what if I want to return both? how can I do that?

Comment: @mots I've updated the answer on how to return multiple values

Comment: Any way to assign the two returns values in a one liner call ?

Comment: @Stephane `const [val1, val2] = [1,2]`, docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: I noticed we may also add types as in `const [ val1, val2 ]: [string, number] = [ 'Stephane', 10 ];`